# Advantage of Asmuth-Bloom secret sharing scheme with polynomial over integers?

Tags: secret-sharing

Currently, I am studying the Asmuth-Bloom secret sharing scheme and want to learn more about its polynomial version.

- What are the exact reasons to use polynomials over integers for this scheme?

Comment: do you have any references to the polynomial version?